# MobaXTerm: how to confirm using keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mobaxterm

In MobaXTerm there are some dialogs, e.g. "do you want to close the following tabs", to be confirmed with the "yes" or the "no" button. How can I press these buttons with the keyboard? Neither Tab nor Ctrl-Tab nor space can be used to activate the buttons

Answer (score 0):

had contact with the developers of MobaXTerm. This was a missing feature which they now added to the newest version